# How to copy the data from local to hive with clear example?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to insert the data from local to hive table but I am not getting proper output. I want with a clearer example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: You need to provide more information like what you've tried, what is the error? You said you're not getting proper output, so what's your expected output and what's the output you're getting? Please update your question with all these details

Comment: After paying heed to what @Olaf and Chaos have said you might wanna have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-DMLOperations  hope it helps..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/dummy.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE dummy`

This is as elaborate as I can get considering the amount of detail in the question

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a table as

Create table charn(id int)

row format delimited

fields terminated by ',';

Then use the following command

Load data local inpath '/usr/loca/charn.csv'overwrite into table charn;

Note your csv file hive record as

1,charn
2,ashu